# Ubuntu 20.10 restarting unexpectedly after automatic sleep

Tags: suspend, restart

I have noticed unexpected restarts when laptop goes to sleep or I am away from it.
It doesn't always happen while in sleep.
It happens only when I leave the laptop without manually suspending it.
If I manually suspend it, it never restarts, but sometimes it doesn't wake again so I have to force shutdown using the power button.

I tried memtest, and searched here and on google but with no use.

Any idea how to diagnose or solve the issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: FYI:  If you're needing to use the power button, and not forcing shutdown via SysRq keyboard commands to the kernel - that's a useful clue; but you didn't mention if you're going to power button because of need, or lack of trying other linux approaches (SysRq keyboard commands allow you to directly command the Linux kernel).

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I will re-install an LTS version and see if the problem persists. regarding your FYI, I'm not sure I got what you mean, but when laptop is in sleep sometimes I can't wake it up no matter what, buttons, combinations, mouse move or clicks, no response at all and screen is completely off. So I finally press & hold power to kill it :(

Comment: The SysRq key is used by the kernel so it knows you want to command it, and not a GUI/programs etc.  It's available on any Linux device with real keyboard (so not android phones as on-screen keyboards use GUI to work) unless disabled. Search "magic sysrq" on a phone & you'll find the wikipedia page which shows combinations. REISUB will safely reboot & is the safer option contrasted with power-button.  If kernel responds you know machine is working (even if screen is stuck!). Clicks require working GUI so little help; keyboard best bet with right keys (not random user-key combinations)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @guiverc